# Moscow subway last train time

Tags: trains, public-transport, buses, moscow, warsaw

I am thinking of flying from Warsaw to Moscow. The problem with the cheap airline air Baltic is that it arrives at `2:00` in the deep night.

Is there still subway to the downtown?

Comment: Arrival in the late night is not specific to "cheap" airlines. Also "expensive " airlines arrive in the middle of the night (e.g. Lufthansa). Personally I made the experience that this is not a disadvantage in Moscow.

Comment: The Metro doesn't reach any of the airports. The last [Aeroexpress](https://aeroexpress.ru/en) trains connecting airports to the city depart at 0:00 or 0:30 depending on airport. The Metro opens at 5:30 and closes at 1:00.

Comment: Which airport?  There's a train out of Domodedovo -> Paveletsky, but no way it runs at 2 AM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At that hour, I presume you are flying Air Baltic BT 416 from Riga to Vnukovo (VKO). You can see the routes on this [route map](https://www.airbaltic.com/en/cheap-flights-to-moscow), enter Moscow on the left and pick Sheremetyevo (SVO) or VKO to see the flights. The only bus is 611 which does not run per this [611 timetable](http://wikiroutes.info/en/msk?routes=1077) this late. The express bus is even more limited per this [611s timetable](http://wikiroutes.info/en/msk?routes=1087).

Answer (score 7):

If your flight arrives in Sheremetievo (BT426), then you may use the [H1](http://www.mosgortrans.ru/uploads/pics/nmH1.jpg) (it's russian N letter) night bus. It goes right through the city center, and at night there will be no traffic jams.

Judging by the [timetable](http://www.mosgortrans.org/pass3/shedule.php?type=avto&way=%CD1&date=1111111&direction=BA&waypoint=all), the first bus leaves the airport at 03:00, which should give you the time to pass the customs, then every half hour.